# CSS horizontal bar that collapses to height of its children (Getting unwanted vertical space)

Tags: html, layout, css

I want a horizontal bar layout that will collapse to the height of its children.

The following example almost gets me there, except I'm getting an unwanted vertical space at the top unless I specifically set the children line-heights to >= 1.4em.

Why doesn't the containing bar fully collapse?

[image]

See http://jsfiddle.net/ymnmT/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hbar hbar1">
    <a>Some button</a><span>Some text</span>
</div>

<div class="hbar hbar2">
    <a>Some button</a><span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*== layout ==*/

.hbar > * {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.hbar1 > * {
    line-height:1em;
}
.hbar2 > * {
    line-height:2em;
}

/*== styles ==*/

.hbar {background:#DDD;margin:10px;}
a {background-color:#FFF;}
span {background:red;}
```

---

(Please note- Looking for a solution that uses inline-block)

Comment: My first thought is that the `display:inline-block;` is making it a larger block element, have you tried inline / floating them?

Comment: @RyanS - The inline-block elements are the height that they are- I see no reason why they should be treated differently height-wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `line-height` of `.hbar` to less than the `line-height` of your child elements that should do the trick. The problem is that the div has a default line-height that is greater than that of the child elements.

Comment: Josh- thanks, but didn't work- reduced the gap but didn't eliminate it: [http://jsfiddle.net/ymnmT/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/ymnmT/4/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting display to inline-block for the div's children and setting a line-height for them as well. It's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to have the div collapse to those children, per the question. Why should the div be taller than the children?

Comment: Ahh sorry, haven't had my coffee this morning.